# Firefox & Chrome download PHP Files. While other browsers work..... :s

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, php, opera

I have a really strange one, and am unsure where to start looking. 
I dont think its a issue with the Server, as no other users have complained about access. 
Also ill provide you with a Link (If i can) and see for yourself if it works.

My Issue is both Firefox and Chrome download the PHP Files. 
While Microsoft IE (Sorry Edge) WOrks fine, and so does opera....

Checked on my mobile device and the website is loading fine.
Whats more funny, is this only happens in the morning. By afternoon it works again.... :s

Here is a screenshot, showing two browsers accessing the site without any issues. 
While Firefox wants to download a file.

If i dont provide the PHP file name, then the page just appears to be blank. 
I have disabled HTAccess as a Temp for the moment, encase re-write rules got abit messed up and there was browser compatibility issues.

[image]

The domain is: 
www.mess-hall.co.uk   (When accessing this URL i get a blank page on FF and Chrome) 
www.mess-hall.co.uk/index.php wants to download the file in Firefox and chrome.

But IE and Opera are okay. 
Chrome on my mobile is working okay too

(I was actually starting to consider a ISP issue (Its dealt with by a 3rd party and not a ISP for security)

Comment: Works fine here on Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, This saved time messing with the server. Ill go back to digging on my PC. Only happened since windows 10 Update. Might try removing all browsers and starting again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of Trial and error, Different browsers, Inspections. 
I figured it out!!!

My Anti Virus was Modifying the head files from the web server, FF and Chrome then are unsure about the file and prompt to downlaod it. 
(This is why the results where so unexpected between different browsers)

The AntiVirus i use is Eset (Nod32) 
After testing i have seen this also happen on Kaspersky

Adding an Exlusion to the Web Safeguard / scanning fixed the issue 
(I was able to replicate the issue on Facebook after a Heavy load of refreshes on the website)

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have set an automatic action on .php files in your browser. For firefox more info could be found at http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions#Setting_an_automatic_action

What is inside the file? Just HTML? If you can find any php in the downloaded file it's somthing wrong with your server othervise it's browser issue.

Works fine form me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by something else beside an Antivirus.
I have the same problem with Pale Moon which is forked from mozilla code, the same one Firefox is based on. Pale Moon tries to download the webpage with a .php extension. So it could be related to a specific browser code quirk.

However I don't use Windows but Linux and don't have an AV.

I do use add-ons, such as adblockers.